# Heap Growth when addSubview and removeFromSuperview

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-management, addsubview

I have a problem with HEAP GROWTH and PERSISTENT elements seen in "Instruments Allocations" when I add a subview and I return to parent. The subview is a simple blank view with a back button added by IB.

In Instruments I see this when I repeat for 6 times the same action using "Mark heap". The cicle is: click on button in parent to add Subview and going back to parent clickng back button in subview:

[image]

I think it would be zero! Is a very simple action.

The code that I use to load the subview in View1Controller.m is:

```
View2Controller *jv;    
jv = [[View2Controller alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:jv.view];
```

And in View2Controller.m I go back

```
-(IBAction) Back {
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    self.view = nil;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know, I'm using Xcode 4.2

Comment: Are you calling `retain` or `release` anywhere? Or in `main.m` is there a line `@autoreleasepool {` ?

Comment: The presence of @autoreleasepool doesn't guarantee the use of ARC in your code. It's an alternative to the classic NSAutoreleasePool. Check for retain/release attributes as suggested and the optional compiler flags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `[self.view removeFromSuperview];` the `self.view` is unlinked from its superview but it's not released. So the memory footprint grows.

In order to avoid the memory leaks you should release the memory by calling the `release` method on View2Controller instance created into your View1Controller.m file.

For example, you can memorize the reference to the View2Controller instance created by setting a property (jv property in this example):

```
View2Controller *view2controllerInstance = [[View2Controller alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]; // create the new instance
self.jv = view2controllerInstance; // memorize the reference
[view2controllerInstance release]; // release the property on view2controller
[self.view addSubview:self.jv.view]; // add the subview
```

The `jv` property should be defined with declaration properties as follow:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) View2Controller *jv;
```

Comment: By this way the first cycle works fine but when I press the button the second time the app crashes in `@synthesize jv;` displaying "Thread 1: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS""

Comment: Yes, it's right. Here is why: 'self.jv = view2controllerInstance;' this statement assigns the new instance reference to the jv property, but, before to do that it call a automatic 'release' on the old instance. So, the '[self.jv release]' is not useful. It's implicit.

Answer (score 0):

In your second code block:

```
-(IBAction) Back {
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    self.view = nil;
}
```

If this is the code thats in your `View2Controller` then the reason that you're having a problem is because you are setting the pointer to the view to nil before the view can properly dealloc itself. During its own dealloc stage it will release the view and properly remove the Interface Builder Elements. Try to remove or comment out the line `self.view = nil;`.

Comment: Without this line the average of heap growth increases to 2,30 KB and the #persistent to 50.

Comment: is this Action part of the `View2Controller`?

Comment: If you are not using arc you can add `[jv release];` just after you add it as a subview. if it yells at you, then you are using ARC. Try that in addition to removing `self.view = nil;`

Comment: If I add `[jv release]` the app crashes when I remove subview.